# Duplicate Symbol Error in NSManagedObject Subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I just simply created a demo project with Core Data.

I created an entity `Userinfo` in my data model. Now I created a `NSManagedObject` subclass of this entity.

Xcode autogenerated these 4 classes.

[image]

Now when I build the project it throws this error:

[image]

I have done everything I know to remove the error of duplicacy but nothing helped.

I think its a Xcode bug. Please help.

Comment: Here is shorter and easier solution for me.
[This is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14449080/8551309)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are generating files which have already been generated for you by Xcode and thus get duplicate declarations. Details about this feature (new in Xcode 8) can be found in [this WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/242/).

Two possible fixes:

**1) Use the Xcode generated `ManagedObject` subclasses (the recommended, modern approach)**

- Delete all generated NSManagedObject subclasses from your project, if exists.
- Set `Codegen`to `Class Definition` in your `.xcdatamodel` for all entities
- Make sure `Module` is empty ("Global Namespace" in light gray) (workaround an Apple bug, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39984888/1457385))

[image]

- Clean project
- [Clean DerivedData folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39867128/1457385) (Optional. To be on the save side)
- build

**Note:**

Never add the automatically generated files to your project. Even you do not see the generated files in your project, Xcode has a reference to it, so you are able to write extensions and such. For instance:

```
extension MyEntity {
    func doSomething() {
        //
    }
}
```

Also, you can command+click to the generated file within Xcode.

**2) Trigger subclass generation manually (a rather paranoid but bullet-prove approach, ignoring the new Xcode features)**

- Delete all generated NSManagedObject subclasses from your project, if exists.
- Set `Codegen`to `Manual/None` in your `.xcdatamodel` for all entities
- Clean project
- [Clean DerivedData folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39867128/1457385)
- Restart Xcode
- Manually generate `NSManagedObject` subclasses (in "Editor" menu)
- Make sure those files are added to your project
- build

Comment: Where are those files generated? Cause I need those classes for my purpose.

Comment: In Derived Data. Do not add them to your project. If you follow the answer, it work, Xcode has a reference to it automatically. You can also write extensions aso. If you have issues, describe the issue you have. I will try to help.