# Can't add NSManagedObject subclass to project

Tags: core-data, xcode8

After creating my Data Model, I'm trying to create an NSManagedObject Subclass for an entity.  In Xcode I click on the entity.  Then from the Editor menu, I'm selecting Create NSManagedObject Subclass.  The issue is the files are added outside the Project.  I can't specify that they should be included in the Project Target.  Screenshots below:
[image]

[image]

Comment: That is a new Xcode feature. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40867271/1457385

Comment: Thanks @shallowThought.  What I ended up doing was simply creating two Swift files within my Project and copied the data out of the two files that were generated.

Comment: I highly recommend against altering generated code in any way. Create the files manually if fine, I do recommend to use the new Xcode feature mentioned in the linked answer though.

Comment: I managed to resolve this.  I'm using Cocoa Pods which creates a workspace.  The reason my NSManagedObject files where not being included in the project was that they were being added to the workspace.  I simply selected the project from the drop down and followed they instructions you sent.  Thanks again!