# Custom methods for CoreData classes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I'm trying to conform to the `MVC paradigm` in my iOS app.  My model consists of entities stored in coreData which I have set up using the `xcdatamodel` file.

I want to add some custom methods to these entities in order to keep the Model part separate from the Controller.

In previous versions of Xcode the autogenerated `managedObject` classes were added automatically to my project and I could add custom methods to these classes.  Now I no longer see these auto genterated classes.

I have selected 'Class Definition' for the codegen.

Do I need to create an additional class for each entity to enable custom methods on those `entities`?  Or is there a better way to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rather new Xcode feature. Xcode generates the files for you and holds a reference to the generated files. Even the files do not show up in the project, you still can write extensions for the generated classes.

You can find more detailed information [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40867271/1457385).

Comment: thanks.  I'll add the extension as mentioned in that post.  as a matter of form and for best practice, where would be the best place to add the extensions for my entities?  In a newly created coreDataHelper class or file?

Comment: That is opinion based and imo. depends. Generally I either have a `StoreWorker` for a topic, for instance `FetchOrdersWorker`, where I put in stuff regarding fetching orders. Sometimes I find it clearer to collect code entity wize. In this case I create a file `EntityName+Additions` where all extensions for `EntityName` are in.

Comment: thanks very much.  I think the EntityName+Additions will fit my project best.